# App crash with our error with Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, crash

I am trying to get an App with Core Data to work, but am running in all kinds of problems.
At the moment the App seems to crash on different placed in the code without giving an error.

Eg. the last thing on the console is:
2

> 010-12-21 16:33:51.295 iDoms[9189:207]
>   CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK,
>   t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDESCRIPTION, t0.ZRSS,
>   t0.ZTYPE, t0.ZID, t0.ZNAME,
>   t0.ZACTIVE, t0.ZLASTUPDATE,
>   t0.ZLANGUAGE FROM ZSITE t0 WHERE 
>   t0.ZID = ? ORDER BY t0.ZNAME DESC
>   LIMIT 1 2010-12-21 16:33:51.296
>   iDoms[9189:207] CoreData: annotation:
>   sql connection fetch time: 0.0011s
>   2010-12-21 16:33:51.297
>   iDoms[9189:207] CoreData: annotation:
>   total fetch execution time: 0.0018s
>   for 1 rows.

HOw can I go about finding out what the problem is?
Any help is really appreciated. I am new to Core Data, and have spend a good few hours to find this problem without any luck.

Update:
After a bit of debugging I found the following:

> Program received signal: 
>   “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. warning: Cancelling
>   call - objc code on the current
>   thread's stack makes this unsafe.

Comment: Try build and analyze for memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was a problem with a lot of memory leaks in the RSS parser I used. I rewrote it with much simpler code and it made the whole application much more stable.